# Create a page without placing .php at the end?

Tags: php, security

I was looking for ways to mimic something I've seen, however I'm really not even sure where to start or how to search for it.

Lets say my page was:

foo.com/ and my index page could take an argument of: index.php?id=5

What I'm wanting to do is create the following:

foo.com/5/ rather than placing index.php?id=5 just use the webstring to pass in the parameters, to hide not only the fact its a PHP page, but to clean up the url a bit more.

Is this possible?

Cheers

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll want to look into URL rewriting. With the commonly used Apache webserver, this is accomplished with [`mod_rewrite`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mod-rewrite).

Comment: Just a note, though this is the correct answer for changing/masking the url. This won't hide the fact your using PHP completely, as the response headers will more than likely contain information about PHP.

Comment: Thank you. Got this working perfect after a little searching on mod_rewrite. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

or /?5/123/
and in php parse the query string if rewrite is not available

Comment: That's a nice one, where mod_rewrite is not available. **But** it depends on a `DirectoryIndex index.php` setting.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should suit:

`RewriteRule ^pages/([A-Za-z_-]*)(/?)$ /index.php?page=$1`

Broken down, we're looking for a URL that starts with pages, has any combination of letters, underscores and hyphens, and an optional trailing forward slash, and passing that to /index.php to handle.

Comment: That won't be very helpful without `RewriteEngine on`... or in IIS. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes Mod_rewrite  is best option, you can create .htaccess file. if you do not want the  write a custom function which will handle the your url.