# PHP page access without extension and variable

Tags: .htaccess

How can I create a PHP page system that we access without `.php` extension and without `?page=` variable?

There's a simple exemple:

```
http://www.exemple.com/portfolio/1
```

Instead of:

```
http://www.exemple.com/portfolio.php?id=1
```

It would be great for me because I'm a web designer and this is a thing I never did. So it would be good to know this! Also I will use this in my website.

Comment: `I think this is very useful if I want to hide my code`  Can you expand on that a bit more? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Much like your other questions (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705457/how-i-can-create-advanced-php-link/8705491#8705491 for example) all you need is mod_rewrite.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a page without placing .php at the end?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455071/create-a-page-without-placing-php-at-the-end)

Comment: @mario Sorry, I didn't see it...

Comment: If you "hate the .htaccess" there is nothing we can do about it. As alternative `MultiViews` might work however.

Comment: What is your web server? IIS, Aapache, ngnix have rewrite capabilities

Comment: .htaccess is to be loved, not to be hated.

Comment: @Shiplu Apache on Zend Server CE for Windows...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you would need the following in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*[^/])/?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%1.php -f
RewriteRule .+ %1.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: yes, that is exactly what it would do. Just remember to change your internal links to match.

Comment: Is there another way? Because the .htaccess doesn't work on my server, but I don't know why....

Comment: .htaccess is by far the simplest way of doing this. Is it that no .htaccess files work on your server, or that THIS .htaccess file wont work?

Comment: then you are probably going to have issues with any possible solution. Why are trying to hide the extension? If its for SEO purposes, don't bother as it makes next to no difference. If its for the look of it, and you can't use .htaccess then its probably not worth the hassle.

Comment: I won't hide extension.. I have no choice!

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/profile$ /account.php?profile [L]
```

Comment: Downvote? Sorry, I'm from Montreal in Canada... So I don't know all of the expression in english...

Comment: @FrederickMarcoux - Someone voted my answer down, I was asking that person to leave a comment explaining their reasoning.

Comment: I didn't downvote. But It seems your rules only applicable for the example of the original poster. It will not solve in general case.

Comment: Ohh, okok, sorry.. It's not me!

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiviews, or better and more used: mod_rewrite module from apache. It can be via a .htaccess file where you create rewrite rules like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)?(.*)$  /$1.php?Action=$2 [L]
```

Comment: The RewriteRule might be better with `RewriteRule ^(.+)$  /$1.php [QSA,L]`?

Comment: True. I saw this question and quickly posted a reply. Thanks for your mention though.

Answer (score 0):

Create .htaccess file in your web root and enter following.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^account/([0-9]+)$ account.php?id=$1
```

---

OR

See [mod_rewrite](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/urlrewriting.html), in case URL rewriting, if you trying to do such.